# Comparing a reversed string to it's original without using .reverse() method

Tags: javascript, string

I'm attempting to compare an original string argument with its reverse. In essence, this function is supposed to verify whether or not a given string is a palindrome. Key points:

1. String needs to be converted to all lowercase, which I did.
2. String needs to consist of only alphanumeric characters, which I did.
3. *When compared, the original string and formatted string must match. If they do, the boolean value of true gets returned, otherwise false does.*

Here is the source code: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ff3xrz3y/1/) | Alternatively, code is below:

```
function palindrome(str) {

  var reverseString;
  var temp;
  var formatted;

  // make sure input gets converted to lowercase  
  temp = str.toLowerCase();

  // make sure all non-alphanumeric characters get removed  
  // once converted to lowercase, ensure that all special characters and digits are stripped from the string
  formatted = temp.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '');


  // now we need to compare two strings: the raw input vs the string in reverse  
  for (i = formatted.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {

    reverseString += formatted[i];
  }
    if (reverseString === str) {
       return true;
  }
    return false;

}


palindrome("123$EYE");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function palindrome(str) {

  var reverseString=""; // initialize every string to ""
  var temp="";
  var formatted="";

  temp = str.toLowerCase();

  formatted = temp.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, ''); // I added 0-9 in your regex to have numbers in your string

  for (i = formatted.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverseString += formatted[i];
  }

    if (reverseString === formatted) { // change str to formatted
       return true;
  }
    return false;
}

var isPal = palindrome("123$EYE");
alert(isPal); // try it on `alert` if it is true or false
```

Your code is ok. But you have some flaws. You should initialize your `String` to `""` so it will not have a value of `undefined`. The one you put on your `if statement` is `str` which is your original String word, you should put your `formatted` String because that is the one you removed the special characters.

Comment: Oh gosh. Thanks! I don't know why I was trying to compare my reversed string to it's original argument.. using the formatted string was the obvious logic. So, with the initialize modifications and the modified logic on my compare operator, most test cases work.. however, if I try to pass an argument like this: palindrome("1 eye for of 1 eye."), I get true when in actuality it should be false. Hm.

Comment: @Cory it will be `true` because if you remove special characters like spaces,period and numbers. the string would be **eyeforofeye**. when you reverse it, it will be the same.

Comment: @Cory remeber that spaces and period are special characters too. you remove the numbers as well in your formatting of strings.

Comment: Hmmm, yes you are right. I failed to consider that for some reason, guess it's part of the learning curve.  Although, according to my specifications.. that specific test case is supposed to return false. Any input on how that is even possible? My only guess is the spaces.. but plenty of other test cases with spaces in them returned the correct value. **edit: actually, I believe it's the numbers.  I believe I need to edit my RegEx to leave them in.

Comment: @Cory there are so many special characters that you wouldn't notice to remove on your strings. so I think, in that case of yours, you should include to remove all possible special characters so only letter characters will remain.

Comment: @Cory if you don't want to remove numeric, just change your regex to `/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g`. so alphanumerics will not be removed as the specifications says.

Comment: Thank you very much, I learned a lot from this discussion. I accepted your submission as the answer, very much appreciated.  Have a great New Year!

Comment: @Cory you will learn new things in your journey towards future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Why reverse and compare? You just need to compare the characters of the same position from the head and from the tail. First `str[0]` and `str[length - 1]`, then `str[1]` and `str[length - 2]`, and so on. Till you reach the middle, or any comparison fails.

```
function isPalindrome(str) {
  var len = str.length
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(len/2); i++) {
    if (str[i] !== str[len - 1 - i]) {
      // or add more comparison rules here
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

isPalindrome('1')    // true
isPalindrome('121')  // true
isPalindrome('1221') // true
isPalindrome('1211') // false
```

Answer (score 1):

alphanumeric characters?

```
function palindrome(str) {
    var temp;
    temp = str.toLowerCase();
    temp = temp.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');
    console.log(temp);
    for (let a = 0, b = temp.length - 1; b > a; a++, b--) {
        if (temp.charAt(a) !== temp.charAt(b))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `reverseString` so it will be `undefined` at the beginning. Adding a character `'a'` to `undefined` returns a string `'undefineda'`, instead of `'a'` which you probably expect.

Change your code to

```
var reverseString = '';
```

and it'll work

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elegant way to reverse the text:

```
var rev = temp.split('').reverse().join(''); // reverse
```

check out fiddle:

```js
function palindrome(str)
{
  var temp = str.toLowerCase() // converted to lowercase  
                .replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ''); // non-alphanumeric characters removed
  var rev = temp.split('').reverse().join(''); // reverse
  console.log(temp, ' === ', rev, ' is ', temp === rev);
  if(temp === rev)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var out = palindrome("123$EYE");
document.getElementById('divOutput').innerHTML = out;
```

```html
<div id="divOutput"></div>
```